# Unexpected data saved in iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, app-store-connect, icloud

One of my apps just got rejected because of the following reason:

> 2.23 - Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected
>
> 2.23 Details
>
> On launch and content download, your app stores 103.72 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

I check my iPhone and my app did save 200+ MB of data to iCloud. However, I am pretty sure all the data in my app are saved with Core Data, and the app doesn't even have iCloud turned on in the Capabilities tab. So is there a way to find out where are these data come from? Or can you suggest somethings that may cause this so I can look into them?

**Edit**

Sorry I missed a line in Apple's feedback:

> For additional information on preventing files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes, see [Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html).

So I think what the reviewer actually meant is that some data that shouldn't be backed up to iCloud are backed up, so all I need to do is something like this:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *) filePathString {
    NSURL* URL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePathString];
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is quite a common issue.*

You can use the following code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to see the permission of each item about iCloud backup:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSArray *documents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:basePath error:nil];
NSURL *URL;
NSString *completeFilePath;

for (NSString *file in documents) {
    completeFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", basePath, file];
    URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:completeFilePath];
    NSLog(@"File %@  is excluded from backup %@", file, [URL resourceValuesForKeys:
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey] 
                                                                             error:nil]);
}
```

If you notice that some files are synchronising with iCloud,instead of saving those files in another place you can set the resource value for the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to `YES` to exclude those files from being backed up by iCloud

**Like this:**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:photoPath];
[URL setResourceValue:@(YES) forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found that I missed a line in Apple's feedback (I've edited the question). Sorry about that.

Comment: my case is I could not find any file in documents, and the back up size is a few KB..